# How to change volume with MPMusicPlayerController without affecting the device volume

Tags: iphone, ipad, avaudioplayer, mpmusicplayercontroller

I am using `MPMusicPlayerController` and `AVAudioPlayer` simultaneously.
For audio balancing, I have two volume sliders for `MPMusicPlayerController` and `AVAudioPlayer` each.
If I mute the `MPMusicPlayer` volume and increases `AVAudioPlayer` volume, the overall device volume mutes and I'm not able to hear the `AVAudioPlayer` sound.

Then, how can I change the `MPMusicPlayer` volume independently, without affecting the device volume.

Answer (score 1):

Prior to iOS 7, there was a volume property on MPMusicPlayer - it was deprecated in iOS7. On AVAudioPlayer there still is a volume property, which you can use to change the instance volume, without affecting the device volume.

Now, in iOS 7, I think you can use:

MPVolumeView